# Problem while instaling wine on 64bit ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management, wine, 64-bit

I am trying to install wine for a long time now and i tried many different ways to do it

i tried installing it using terminal :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
sudo app-get update
sudo app-get install wine1.7
```

then i get this error :

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

after this error i did

```
sudo app-get install <depended package name> (in this case wine1.7-i386)
```

I repeat this till i get to this error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libfontconfig1:i386 : Depends: fontconfig-config:i386 (= 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After this i type `sudo apt-get install fontconfig-config:i386` and i get this error :

```
Note, selecting 'fontconfig-config' instead of 'fontconfig-config:i386'
fontconfig-config is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

i found this way of doing it here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2048092

also i tried installing using synaptic package manager but i get this error

```
wine1.7:
 Depends: wine1.7-amd64 but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.18-0ubuntu1)
```

Comment: The best method of finding missing dependencies is: **`sudo apt-get install -f`** *However, you first need to resolve how to force **32-bit** Wine, under **12.04 LTS** 64-bit.*

Comment: **Broader issue:** *If you are trying to run a newer revision (of Wine), you should be also (at least) on **14.04 LTS**.*

Comment: Partial solution (untested): http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-wine-1-7-20-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install `fontconfig-config:i386 (= 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1)` because 12.04 has a dependency.
There was a metapackage which depend on fontconfig-config 2.10.x, so you should remove it.

How to find it? For example use aptitude:

1. Remove `fontconfig-config 2.10.x`.
2. Install `fontconfig-config:i386 (= 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1)`
3. Search broken meta-packages, which needs 2.10.x exactly.
4. Remove the meta-package.
5. Dependencies should solved automatically.